# How do I respond to "you're welcome" when I didn't say "thank you"?

Tags: saying-thanks

Someone tells me "you're welcome" but I didn't say "thank you." Should I thank them now, or is it too late?

Context: Sometimes I forget to thank people. Other times people say "you're welcome" to tell me that I should have thanked them, but I didn't think a "thanks" was even necessary.

Comment: In what context?

Comment: You can literally respond anyway you want. We're not here to tell you what to do you need to decide that for yourself. Could you [edit] this question to add some context and explain what sort of outcome you are trying to get with your response?

Comment: How did you want/try to respond? Why didn't that (or do you think it won't) work for you? Also is this at work? At a family function? When you're hanging out with friends? The etiquette in each of these situations will be vastly different. As it stands now, your question looks too broad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably. Generally the only reason someone does that is as a slightly snarky way to remind you to thank them. But don't just say "thankyou" as though it's an automatic response. Either

- apologize for the omission "sorry, I didn't thank you for [action/item]. [Optional: an explanation of unusual circumstances eg I've been awake 36 hours.] [
  [SMILE. You are grateful for the course correction.]
- look puzzled like you don't know why they're saying that to you. This applies if you didn't need to thank them for their action. (As a Canadian I'm a bit of an overthanker so am having trouble coming up with an example. Maybe if you held a door for someone and they said "you're welcome" as they went through.)

Don't just thank them. If nothing else, make a note that this person likes to be thanked, and be sure to do it next time.